# Como fazer para o ProGuard remover um método de classe?

Tags: java, proguard

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que o ProGuard 4.10 faça com que um método `static` vire *inline*. Só consigo isso com métodos de instância.

Por exemplo, esse pequeno trecho:

```
public final class Calc {
    private int x = 0;
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = s.nextInt();

        Calc c = new Calc();
        int res = c.getX();
        if ((c.getX() & 1) != 0)
            res++;
        else
            res += 2;
        c.setX(res);

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Depois de processado pelo ProGuard se transforma em (desconsiderando a ofuscação):

```
public final class Calc {
    private int x = 0;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = s.nextInt();

        Calc c = new Calc();
        int res = c.x;
        if ((c.x & 1) != 0)
            res++;
        else
            res += 2;
        c.x = res;

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Contudo, se adapto as classes, e transformo os métodos em `static`, esse trecho abaixo **não se altera** (desconsiderando a ofuscação):

```
public final class Calc {
    private static int x = 0;
    public static int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public static void setX(int x) {
        Calc.x = x;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = s.nextInt();

        int res = Calc.getX();
        if ((Calc.getX() & 1) != 0)
            res++;
        else
            res += 2;
        Calc.setX(res);

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Para sanar qualquer dúvida, eis a configuração que estou utilizando em ambos os casos:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-optimizationpasses 9
-allowaccessmodification
-mergeinterfacesaggressively
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontpreverify
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver
-keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
    public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Estou errando alguma coisa? Falta alguma opção para fazer com que o ProGuard otimize e faça métodos `static` *inline*?

Já essas três documentações (além de muitas outras) e não encontrei nada mencionando esse caso. Seria isso uma limitação do ProGuard?

[Optimizations](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/optimizations.html)

[Usage](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html)

[Examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html)

Comment: Não sei se já resolveu, mas vê se isso te ajuda:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452928/remove-unused-classes-with-proguard-for-android

Comment: @AlbertoLourenço Valeu, mas não é bem isso ainda :( Eu preciso fazer com que um método `static` de uma classe seja substituído por seu conteúdo. Mas, valeu! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

espero poder ajuda-lo depois de tanto tempo, segue minha resposta:

> Estou errando alguma coisa? Falta alguma opção para fazer com que o
>   ProGuard otimize e faça métodos static inline?

Não, o [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) não faz [inlining](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Inlining) de metódos de classes (ou superclasses) que tenham inicializadores estaticos, seus **metodos acessores estáticos** podem disparar um **inicializador estático**, podendo causar problemas na aplicação fora do escopo de analise do *"compilador"*, por exemplo: 
A declaração estática de **x**:

```
private static int x = 0;
```

*Faz com que **Calc** tenha um inicializador estático implicito*:

```
public final class Calc {
    private static int x;
    static { // inicializador estatico implicito 
     x = 0; 
    }
   // ... continua ...
}
```

Suponhamos que tenhamos um inicializador estático em classe ou superclasses, :

```
static { 
 setupDatabaseConfig(); 
}
```

Sei que não é o seu caso, mas ter certeza que nenhum problema ocorra foi inserido esse critério de corte, até que se refine a ["Escape Analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) das otimizações de inlining e que possa garantir que não ocorra problemas colaterais em situações elegíveis. 

Confesso que fiz alguns testes (com seu exemplo) na última [versão (5.2) do Proguard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/) e não obtive sucesso no inlining. Mas mesmo assim recomendo a última versão (pois houveram refinamentos).

*Segue o método do [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), que se resguarda ao executar inlining em métodos estáticos e em subsets não inicializados*:
*Trecho de* **[MethodInliner.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.proguard/proguard-base/5.1/proguard/optimize/peephole/MethodInliner.java#MethodInliner.visitProgramMethod%28proguard.classfile.ProgramClass%2Cproguard.classfile.ProgramMethod%29)**:

```
 // Only inline the method if it comes from the a class with at most
    // a subset of the initialized superclasses.
    ((accessFlags & ClassConstants.ACC_STATIC) == 0 ||
     programClass.equals(targetClass)                        ||
     initializedSuperClasses(targetClass).containsAll(initializedSuperClasses(programClass))))
```

*ps: Sendo o caso posso compilar uma versão do Proguard ignorando o criterio de exclusão de inicializadores estáticos do inlining e você pode utilizar para fins especificos.*

Comment: Reginaldo, estou chocado com seu nível de conhecimento sobre o assunto! Muito obrigado! Agradeço a "versão customizada" do Proguard, mas o projeto roda em diferentes máquinas, e *deve* utilizar a versão padrão. Mas, fiquei curioso quanto a uma coisa: o simples acesso a um campo de uma classe A a partir de outra classe B já não é o suficiente para disparar o inicializador estático de A? Por exemplo class A { public static int x; ... } class B { ... void m() { A.x = 9; } ... }

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn, em tempo de execução qualquer classe carregada ao classloader terá seu inicializador estático executado, o problema ocorre ao efetuar uma analise estática de uma sub rotina global (static), quando não sabemos exatamente o momento do seu acionamento, em escape analysis consideramos que "pointer has escaped", por isso método estáticos -geralmente não são otimizados- pelo seu aspecto global, o mesmo (inlined) poderia estar sendo chamado em uma inicialização estática, por isso o ProGuard só faz inline em métodos classes e subsets inicializadas não estáticas.

Comment: Entendi! O problema é na fase da análise estática! Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!!! :D